# Why Signal R is taking a lot of time to hit

Tags: .net, signalr, signalr-hub, signalr.client

Why my signal r calls are happening so slow?
I am trying to hit Add Users to ongoing session, but it take a lot og time to hit this function

```
_hubConnection = new HubConnection(hubURL);
IHubProxy _hubProxy = _hubConnection.CreateHubProxy("usersessionhub");
if (_hubConnection.State == ConnectionState.Disconnected)
{
   _hubConnection.Start().Wait();
}
await _hubProxy.Invoke("AddUserToOngoingSession", userToJoin.userId, AssociationDetails);
```

Follwing is the function i am calling

```
public void AddUserToOngoingSession(var userId,var AssociationDetails)
{
    Clients.Client(ConnectionId).sendAssociationDetails(AssociationDetails); 
    Clients.Client(ConnectionId).sendUserId(userId); 
}
```

Running it on localhost.

Comment: what does "a lot of time" mean? Do you use scale out? Where are you connecting - localhost or across the world? Have you compared it to the time it takes to send a regular http request?

Comment: @Pawel I am running it on localhost, Http request are occurring at a relatively very less time , sometimes the signal r calls happens instantly, bt sometimes it doesnt hit for a while and then all calls hits simultaneously

Comment: Do you send other requests to the same server/from the same browser? Maybe you are hitting some kind of limits which will make requests queue. There are a browser limit and a server limit (if you are running IISExpress).

Comment: @Pawel Yes, a number of users are connected in the same browser with different tabs. Will host it on IIS and see if a number of users on different devices can hit it.